# Relative paths to bundles in index.html

Tags: svelte

I have a small svelte-application, that is accessed through a reverse proxy. The app is accessed under a path, like http://host/appname, and the proxy rule fetches content from http://localhost:port. The svelte-app is listening to the same port.

When I load http://host/appname/index.html, the file is fetched as expected, but the js and css bundles have an absolute path, like '/bundle.js'. This makes the browser trying to fetch http://host/bundle.js, which of course fails. If the links in index.html were relative, like './bundle.js', things would work better, since the browser would expand it to http://host/appname/bundle.js, which is where the files are.

How can I make svelte produce relative paths to my bundles?

Comment: If you're using [sveltejs/template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template), the Rollup config doesn't produce `index.html`, that's all modified by you. Also, you define the output name and location in `rollup.config.js`.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your own `public/index.html` template and define the links to the CSS and JS bundles to suit your project. For example, if both bundles are output into the `public` directory as well:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>

    <title>Svelte app</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bundle.css'>

    <script defer src='bundle.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you can set the output directory for both bundles (CSS & JS) in your rollup configuration file.

Comment: Ahh, so it was that easy... I thought index.html was generated by the build.

Comment: @hellmelt It is, unless you provide one yourself when you need a specific setup ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found not very convient with a static generated site. Especially with development and

1. add `<base href="/abc/">` to the `index.html` file.
2. use `svelte-routing` with `Router` for SPA navigation.

```
<Router basepath="/abc">
...
</Router>
```

I suggest use `sveltekit`